# Why does Auto List Members keep getting turned off?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, sometimes within the same session (not having rebooted the app) intellisense gets turned off. The checkboxes in Tools > Options > Text Editory > C# > Statement Completion, "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information" become unchecked.

I have Resharper installed as well. But Resharper does not control that setting, as far as I know.

This can happen a couple times a day to me, all without restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Seems to happen in R# 7.0.1 as well.

Comment: Happens to me everytime i build my project using Resharper 8.1

Comment: Still happening in VS 2022 with ReSharper 2023.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, apparently, a documented bug for Resharper: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/02/resharper-513-is-released/

Excerpt:

```
ReSharper 5.1.3 provides exactly one bug fix that prevents disabling Parameter
Information and auto-completion when you’re using native Visual Studio 
IntelliSense (as opposed to ReSharper IntelliSense).

Please note that if you’re been using ReSharper IntelliSense as a workaround in 
5.1.2, as soon as you switch back to Visual Studio IntelliSense, you’ll have to    
initially set Auto-list members and Parameter information check boxes manually, 
but that is only required once.
```

Answer (score 6):

I've noticed this in ReSharper 7.1.1 as well, at least regarding javascript intellisense having the same problem. My workaround was to tell Reshaper to use 'Visual Studio' as its Intellisense option Resharper > Options > Intellisense > General. (you can still bring up Resharper's intellisense with Ctrl + Alt + Space)

Once I did that it kept my Visual Studio options checked for good.

Comment: Same things been happening with ReSharper 8.2 for me. This took care of the issue.