# How to keep "Hide advanced members" unchecked for all languages in visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, checkbox, visual-studio-2013, settings

In Visual Studio 2013, under the menu setting:

`Tools>Options>Text Editor>All Languages>General>Statement Completion`

If i uncheck the `Hide advanced members` checkbox, click Ok and close the options window, the checkbox is checked again the options menu is opened back up again, the same thing if you close and reopen VS after changing the setting.

Am i missing something? Couldn't find anything on web mentioning this issue. How can i keep it unchecked?

Comment: Long time later ( 11 months later ) and I see no answers... I'm looking at the same issue. Are you using Resharper and-or web-essentials? I was trying to disable the advanced members, because I'm using TypeScript and only want to see my members. (this seems very similar to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345570/why-does-auto-list-members-keep-getting-turned-off )